# googleSample mvp-todo-dagger2

Tags: android, mvp, dagger

I work with googleSample mvp-todo-dagger2 Click [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/);

In my App One Activity has two Fragment,How to Inject two PresenterModule to one
Activity?

Answer (score 0):

you must inject the presenters in your fragments instead of activity. every view in MVP pattern has its own responsibility and you better inject every presenter only in its specific views.

use separate view contracts for each of your fragments and implements those contracts and inject their corresponding presenters separately in each of them.

look at [this](https://gitlab.com/amirziarati/Echarge) project of mine. i have an activity called `PackagePeriodsActivity` which has a viewpager in it, then in this view pager there are multiple `PeriodsFragment`that injects its own presenter in itself not in its activity.